# Class that imports FX Rates from Excel File

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class that imports the FX Rates produced by another department.

This works as intended, which is to return a Pandas DataFrame with all FX Rates by month.

The DataFrame it returns is then used by another 5 classes, that basically import other files and do some formatting and calculations with their own columns, always using the FX Rates from the FxRates class.

I run this code in a Jupyter Notebook.

I want to know if:

1. Code is **refactored enough** or **over-refactored**
2. Is it good practice to update the instance variables as I have done so?
3. Is there anything else that stands out as being bad practice?

```
class FxRates:
    def __init__(self, reporting_date):
        self.reporting_date = reporting_date
        self.path = self.get_path()

    def get_path(self):
        """Get path for the Fx Rates."""
        content_list = listdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Data'))
        file_path = os.path.join(
            os.getcwd(),
            'Data',
            list(filter(lambda x: 'FX rates' in x, content_list))[0]
        )

        return file_path
    
    def reporting_date_check(self):
        """
        Check if date input follows the criteria below:
        31/12/yyyy, 31/03/yyyy, 30/06/yyyy, 30/09/yyyy
        """

        accepted_dates = [
            '31/12',
            '31/03',
            '30/06',
            '30/09'
        ]
        
        # Check if first 5 characters match accepted_dates
        if self.reporting_date[:5] in accepted_dates:
            reporting_date = pd.to_datetime(self.reporting_date,
                                            dayfirst=True)
            self.reporting_date = reporting_date
        else:
            # If not, raise ValueError
            raise ValueError(
        """reporting_date does not match one of the following:
        31/12/yyyy, 31/03/yyyy, 30/06/yyyy, 30/09/yyyy"""
        )


    def import_excel_rates(self):
        """Import FX Rates in Excel file from Group."""
        
        rates = pd.read_excel(self.path,
                              sheet_name='historic rates',
                              skiprows=2,
                              header=None,
                              usecols='B:O',
                              skipfooter=1)
        
        return rates
    

    def EWI_check(self, rates):
        """
        Check if the reporting month already has FX Rates defined.
        If not, copy FX Rates from previous month.
        """

        # For EWI we need to use FX Rates from 1 month before
        if pd.isnull(rates.iloc[0, self.reporting_date.month]):
            print("""
            \n########## Warning ##########:
            \nThere are no FX Rates for {0}/{1}.
            \nFX Rates being copied from {2}/{3}.\n""".format(
                rates.columns[self.reporting_date.month],
                self.reporting_date.year,
                rates.columns[self.reporting_date.month - 1],
                self.reporting_date.year
            ))

            # Copy FX Rates from previous month
            rates.iloc[:, self.reporting_date.month] = \
            rates.iloc[:, self.reporting_date.month - 1]

        else:
            pass

        return rates


    def import_rates(self):
        """
        Import Group Fx rates into a Pandas Dataframe
        """

        # Check if reporting date is correct
        self.reporting_date_check()

        # Import FX Rates in Excel file
        rates = self.import_excel_rates()

        # Set column headers manually
        rates.columns = ['ISO Code',
                         'December ' + str(self.reporting_date.year - 1),
                         'January',
                         'February',
                         'March',
                         'April',
                         'May',
                         'June',
                         'July',
                         'August',
                         'September',
                         'October',
                         'November',
                         'December']

        # Set ISO Code as Index
        rates.index = rates['ISO Code'].values
        rates.drop('ISO Code', axis=1, inplace=True)

        # Check if we have FX Rates for the reporting month
        # If not, copy from last month
        return self.EWI_check(rates)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A note on terminology

"Refactored enough" is only meaningful relative to the code's current state and how it was before; but "over-refactored" is kind of meaningless. I guess the only time that idea could even be applicable is if refactoring occupied too much time or too many corporate resources. Maybe you mean over-abstracted, but that's conjecture. Anyway.

### Type hints

`reporting_date` could stand to get a type hint, likely `: str` given your later usage of this variable.

### Pathlib

Consider replacing `listdir`, `os.path.join` and `os.getcwd` with `pathlib.Path` equivalents, which are typically better-structured and have nice object representations for paths.

### Parsing

Don't store the string representation of `reporting_date`. Do something in the constructor like `self.reporting_date = self.parse_date(reporting_date)`, where the latter is a static method to replace your current `reporting_date_check`. This method would not mutate member variables and would simply return the date once it's figured that out.

### Sets

```
        accepted_dates = [
            '31/12',
            '31/03',
            '30/06',
            '30/09'
        ]
```

should be a class static, initialized via set literal - something like

```
class FxRates:
    ACCEPTED_DATES = {
        '31/12',
        '31/03',
        '30/06',
        '30/09',
    }
```

That said, the approach is a little backwards. You should not do string comparison on the string-formatted date. Parse it first, then do validation on its integer parts after. The accepted dates above can turn into a set of 2-tuples, `(day, month)`.

### Heredocs

This:

```
            print("""
            \n########## Warning ##########:
            \nThere are no FX Rates for {0}/{1}.
...
```

is problematic. You're packing a bunch of whitespace in there that you shouldn't. One solution is to move the string to a global constant to avoid the indentation; you should also replace the explicit `\n` with actual newlines in the string. Another solution is to keep the text where it is but replace it with a series of implicit-concatenated strings, one per line, i.e.

```
print(
    "########## Warning ##########:\n"
    "There are no FX Rates for {0}/{1}.\n"
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And about the refactoring, I definitely meant "over-abstracted". I've read so much about functions that "do one thing, and one thing only" that now I'm paranoid about putting 2 actions in the same function. So, in your opinion, does the code above have a good balance between what each function does?

Comment: Seems pretty good to me